# flow - What kind can I use for the history.push of the react router using Flow for typing?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

What type can I use for the history.push of the react router using Flow for typing?

```
type State = {
    ...
    history: string,
}
```

I use the react router to route to the route when the login is done successfully

```
 history.push("/user");
```

But the following error appears and I did not find the type in flow

```
Cannot call `history.push` because property `push` is missing in `String` [1]. (References: [1])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have the history object typed as a `string`, which is why the error is complaining about strings not having a push property. The history type should be `RouterHistory` from the flow-typed definition: https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x/flow_v0.63.x-/react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js#L57